# Firestore Firebase make Query by documentID, swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a collection called users.
I want to be able to search if a user exists and if so display its documents.

I've tried 2 options which both don't seem to work

```
  db.collection("users").whereField(DocumentID == "max")
            .getDocuments()
```

second way

```
db.collection("users").whereField("Max", isEqualTo: true)
            .getDocuments()
```

[please find image of my database attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKAUH.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()

let docRef = db.collection("collectionName").document("documentName")

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let password = document.get("fieldName")
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

Edit: Looking at your code, I think you are mixing up collections, documents and fields.

The collection in your case is "users", the documents are the second column in your image, eg. Arthur, Fredrick etc. Within the document of say Arthur, is the field: password. So it goes collection → document → field.

Comment: worked like a charm. Thanks ever so much .... this is the line i was hunting for "if let document = document, document.exists "